# Что за тип данных в awk?

Tags: awk

Где найти описание типа данных. В скрипте bash использование примерно такой конструкции: `words[$i]` и написал с помощью неё скрипт, считающий количество слов в файле:

```
cat /d/Bulychev.txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS="(\xc2\xa0|\x20|\xe2\x80\x94|,)"} {for (i = 1; i < NF; i++){if ($i != "") {words[$i]++}}} END {for (i in words) {printf "%10s%25s\n", words[i], i}}' | sort -r > /d/res.txt
```

Но не могу понять, что это за тип данных words[$i]? Это же не массив?

Comment: _где найти описание типа данных_, $ man awk. Уточните пожлуйста, что вы там не поняли?

Comment: words — ассоциативный массив http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_12.html

Comment: @andreymal, cпасибо за ссылку! Описание такого массива не нашёл ни в одной книжке по Линуксу

Comment: @andreymal нашёл теперь у Роббинса "Руководство пользователя для GNU Awk", нужно было знать что искать) Ещё раз спасибо!